# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Promise<number>' and '1' have no overlap

Tags: angular

I am trying to change the label from "pending" or "pendiente" to "pending-rejected" or "pendiente-rechazado". And as it sounds as a simple change, it's not from what I am trying to do.

this is the function I am using to get the logs of every row.

```
  async getLogs(formId: string) {
    (await this.supervisorService.getLogs(formId)).subscribe((logs) => {
      console.log("historic length: "+logs.length);
      console.log("onelog: "+logs[0].ID_ESTADO);
      console.log("logs: "+logs.length);
      this.rejectStatus=0;
      for(var i=0; i < logs.length; i++){
        if(logs[i].ID_ESTADO==1227){
          this.rejectStatus=1;
        }
      }      
    });
    return this.rejectStatus;
  }
```

and this is how I am trying to apply this in the html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="lastLog">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Estado</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <div *ngIf="getLogs(row.ID_FORM) === 1 ; else elseBlock">
      {{row?.lastLog?.ID_ESTADO}}
      Pendiente-Rechazado
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <app-state [state]="row?.lastLog?.ID_ESTADO"></app-state>
    </ng-template>        
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

but I am getting the error:

> error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the
> types 'Promise' and '1' have no overlap.

What can I do, since the solutions I read about it don't work for the HTML.

Here you can find both files:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t5dfrq?file=src/app/forms-table/forms-table.component.html

Comment: Can you call this getLog on ngOnInit and then do something like this? ` <div *ngIf="rejectStatus === 1 ; else elseBlock">
`
I'm just guessing though, if you can share a stackblitz that would be great,

Comment: @amnah Hey, I just updated this and added the stackblitz, which of course its more like a visual help, because it wont compile since this a very complex project. Hope you can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, binding a function to a structural directive like `*ngIf` is inelegant since the function would be triggered for each change detection cycle (with default CD strategy). Combining it with a (possible?) HTTP request might lead to multiple simulatneous HTTP requests.
2. Instead of looping the array manually, you could use the JS `Array#some` function.

Try the following changes

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
// I assume the material table input is initialized in a subscription

this.someService.fetchData().pipe(
  switchMap((res: any) =>            // <-- switch to another observable
    this.supervisorService.getLogs(res.ID_FORM).pipe(  
      map(logs => ({                 // <-- map to transform data
        ...res,                      // <-- spread operator to retain old values
        rejected: logs.some(log => log.ID_ESTADO == 1227)
      }))
    )
  )
).subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => this.someVar = res,
  error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
});
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="lastLog">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Estado</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <div *ngIf="row?.rejected; else elseBlock">
      {{row?.lastLog?.ID_ESTADO}}
      Pendiente-Rechazado
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <app-state [state]="row?.lastLog?.ID_ESTADO"></app-state>
    </ng-template>        
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Totally agree with point 1, but I can not implement this since I just arrived at this project. I just added a stackblitz link to help the visualization. I hope you can check it.

Comment: @FeberCastellon: I'm sorry I can't fix the code. It has got multiple nested subscriptions and it would take longer than I'd to invest. I could see using a `ReplaySubject` with buffer `1` to hold the current `forms`, using `switchMap` to map b/n different observables, `tap` to perform side-effects, using `async` pipe in the template to initialize the table initially.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with
`*ngIf="rejectStatus"`

If it is 1, then condition is true, else it is false. Also no need to return the same, in the function. You just need to set the value for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, this is what worked for me in the end:

the ts file (and of course, the getForms function is always running in ngOnInit):

```
  getLogs(formId: string, index: number) {
        
      this.supervisorService.getLogs(formId).subscribe((logs) => {
        console.log("historic length: "+logs.length);
        console.log("onelog: "+logs[0].ID_ESTADO);
        console.log("logs: "+logs.length);
        this.rejectStatus=0;
        console.log("initial reject status: "+this.rejectStatus);
        
        for(var i=0; i < logs.length; i++){
          if(logs[i].ID_ESTADO==1227){
            this.rejectStatus=1;
          }
        }        
        this.data[index].rejectStatus=this.rejectStatus;
        console.log("counter: "+index);
      });
      console.log("final reject status: "+this.rejectStatus);
    
  }

  async getForms() {
    (await this.supervisorService.getForms())
    .subscribe(async (forms) => {      
      for(var y=0; y<forms.length; y++ ){  
        await this.getLogs(forms[y].ID_FORM, y);
      }
      this.dataSource.data = forms;
      this.data = forms;
      console.log("actual data: "+this.data);
    });
  }
```

and this the html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="lastLog">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Estado</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <div *ngIf="row.rejectStatus === 1 ; else elseBlock">
      Pendiente-Rechazado
    </div>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <app-state [state]="row?.lastLog?.ID_ESTADO"></app-state>
    </ng-template>        
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

thank you all, especially the last answer, because even if it was not good applied, it gave me a new perspective of this problem.